# Is there way to detect player self_muted on discord with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I wanna make among us Discord bot which is automatic mute and unmute system and I have to know the selected player is muted or not 'cause that player will control all player mute system so I wanna ask is there way to detect player self_muted on discord with discord.js (p.s It's ok with python.)

Answer (score 1):

To find out if a user is self muted, use [`VoiceState#selfMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=selfMute):

```js
// If member is a GuildMember:
const selfMuted = member.voice.selfMute
```

Comment: what should i have to put member (player's ID or mention)

Comment: @panda Because you didn't provide any of your existing code, it's hard for me to tell you what exactly should go there. It could be `message.member`, `message.mentions.members.first()`, `guild.member('member id')`, etc.